# Olingo JPA Odata Producer- How to insert record when there is an association between entities

Tags: jpa, odata, olingo

I have created an oData producer using olingo+JPA with MYSQL Db having northwind implementation.
I have a table northwind.inventory_transactions which has fk relation with northwind.inventory_transaction_types, This gets converted to object relation in JPA. When I do get using odata, i get following response:

GET Request
http/localhost:8080/sample/galaxyService.svc/InventoryTransactions?$format=json&$top=1

> { d: { results: [ {
>   __metadata: { id: "http/localhost:8080/sample/galaxyService.svc/InventoryTransactions(35)",
>   uri:
>   "http/localhost:8080/sample/galaxyService.svc/InventoryTransactions(35)",
>   type: "sample.InventoryTransaction" }, Comments: null, Customer: 4,
>   Extra: null, Id: 35, InventoryTransactionType: 1, Order: null,
>   PurchaseOrder: null, Quantity: 75, TransactionCreatedDate:
>   "/Date(1143023548000)/", TransactionModifiedDate:
>   "/Date(1143023548000)/", Weight: "0", CustomerDetails: {
>   __deferred: {`enter code here` uri: "http/localhost:8080/sample/galaxyService.svc/InventoryTransactions(35)/CustomerDetails"
>   } }, InventoryTransactionTypeDetails: {
>   __deferred: { uri: "http/localhost:8080/sample/galaxyService.svc/InventoryTransactions(35)/InventoryTransactionTypeDetails"
>   } }, OrderDetails: {
>   __deferred: { uri: "http/localhost:8080/sample/galaxyService.svc/InventoryTransactions(35)/OrderDetails"
>   } }, ProductDetails: {
>   __deferred: { uri: "http/localhost:8080/sample/galaxyService.svc/InventoryTransactions(35)/ProductDetails"
>   } }, PurchaseOrderDetails: {
>   __deferred: { uri: "http/localhost:8080/sample/galaxyService.svc/InventoryTransactions(35)/PurchaseOrderDetails"
>   } }, PurchaseOrderDetailDetails: {
>   __deferred: { uri: "http/localhost:8080/sample/galaxyService.svc/InventoryTransactions(35)/PurchaseOrderDetailDetails"
>   } } } ] } }

While trying POST operation on same using POSTMAN plugin, I am getting exception as ""
Below is request
POST http/localhost:8080/sample/galaxyService.svc/InventoryTransactions

{
"Comments": "",
"Customer": 4,
"Extra": null,
"Order": null,
"PurchaseOrder": null,
"InventoryTransactionType":1,
"Quantity": 75,
"TransactionCreatedDate": "/Date(1143023548000)/",
"TransactionModifiedDate": "/Date(1143023548000)/",
"Weight": "0"

}
Error:

> Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'transaction_type' cannot be null Error Code: 1048
>   Call: INSERT INTO inventory_transactions (ID, COMMENTS, EXTRA,
>   QUANTITY, transaction_created_date, transaction_modified_date, WEIGHT,
>   CustomerCode, transaction_type, customer_order_id, PRODUCT_ID,
>   purchase_order_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>     bind => [12 parameters bound] Query:
>   InsertObjectQuery(model.InventoryTransaction@63adef6d)

Can someone please guide how to do post where we have relationship like this?

Thanks,
Anubhav.